# Read text file in java eclipse as 2d array error

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I have this code to read data from text file and assign it to 2d array

```
Scanner read_blockage = null;
General_Inputs.Blockage_Number=new double[Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Analysis_Years*Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_States][Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes];
    try{
    read_blockage=new Scanner(new File("Blockage Output1"));
    int row = -1; // since we're incrementing row at the start of the loop
    while(read_blockage.hasNext()) {
        row++;
        String[] line = read_blockage.nextLine().split("\t");
        for(int j=0;j<Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes;j++){
            try {
                General_Inputs.Blockage_Number[row][j] = Double.parseDouble(line[j]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
    read_blockage.close();}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Blockage Output1 (The system cannot find the file specified)
2
2
2
3
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at Input.Get_Inputs(Input.java:270)
    at Input.main(Input.java:288)
```

I am not sure why this error occur any recommendation?

Edit:
I get rid of the above error but now I have a new error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.2810496821150867                           0.3455471819235053                           0.1247760656600859                           0.1925735036025203                           0.16475561749067555                           0.3267969645821732                           0.5325079154577266                           0.7311354592633524                           0.29828747755582985                           0.3983939064000447                           1.6432540332118697                           2.242416989842468                           0.8199042126197025                           1.1448149650482649                           0.6569387483611318                           0.35521248909704994                           0.8311372587904973                           1.2599707232227086                           1.4153816162469934                           1.091443886313361                           0.7492391207620115                           1.4029328027711394                           1.3060173850919903                           3.0212129386585675                           1.185220575726193                           3.2093022651230037                           2.2304670167490195                           4.028061408800144                           1.1957020911741867                           2.3250822033050813                           6.144104904071859                           9.634733755857885                           3.3148373093880736                           9.740483573762857                           3.857137427951027                           4.527035922001198                           7.248709304936811                           10.112180962036412                           12.688211002013142                           3.5445943135631026                           5.87022858087266                           11.490999298946353                           13.75534054772614"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Input.Get_Inputs(Input.java:277)
    at Input.main(Input.java:288)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Input.Get_Inputs(Input.java:277)
    at Input.main(Input.java:288)
```

any recommendation?

Comment: Does the file `Blockage Output1` exist? Is it located in the process's working directory?

Comment: @hexafraction yes I just edit the post it exist at the start of the method. This code is part of much bigger code

Comment: No, I mean the text file called "Blockage Output1" itself. Does it exist on disk? Are you sure it's not called "Blockage Output1.txt"?

Comment: yes it exist its in the directory of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is pretty useful and it's saying that the program can't find the file wherever you're pointing with your file declaration.

Try using an absolute path to the file "Blockage Output1", and remember to include the file extension (.txt, .conf, .bla).

```
//correcting the escape sequence usage
new File("C:\\workspace\\project\\Blockage Output1.txt")
```

Eclipse will look in the root directory of your project for files defined relatively, so if you have the file in a folder such as src, bin, res, then you'll need to declare the file like so.

```
//correcting the escape sequence usage
new File("src\\Blockage Output1.txt")
```

Hope one of these solutions works for you!

Comment: When I tried to use an absolute path to the file "Blockage Output1" I get this error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: I typed this: read_blockage=new Scanner(new File("C:\Users\ahmadgmsalt535465123\Desktop\MOEAFramework-2.3\Blockage Output1.txt"));

Comment: My apologies, you'll need to escape the backslashes and so you'll want to do `new File("C:\\Users\\ahmadgmsalt535465123\\Desktop\\MOEAFramework-2.3\\Blockage Output1.txt")`

Comment: @ Tresdon Its work I got rid of the previous error but I get new error please see my edit

Comment: @jonetravolta I recommend that you analyze your error message and look for some things to tip you off as to what's going wrong there. (for instance the word `String` in `NumberFormatException`). Since stackoverflow.com likes to keep things neat, it is preferential to close this question by accepting an answer that helped you and if you're still struggling with an issue to open a new question for it. This helps people in the future with the same question as you so that they know what helped you and it has a chance of helping them. Thanks!